# Regular Expression: Retrieve a string which matches the head and tail

Tags: python, regex

I am new to RE. Actually I have a long string which is like below:

```
[
   'https://sample.com/templates/sample/assets/img/menu.png' 
   'https://abcd.sample.com/templates/cp/assets/img/1_fs?123456' 
   'https://sample.com/templates/cp/js/plugins/sample/sample.css'
]
```

what I want to retrieve is the string in the middle: `https://abcd.sample.com/templates/cp/assets/img/xyz1_fs?123456`

which as you can see matches the head:`https://abcd.sample.com` and the tail `_fs?123456`.

Comment: If you want to avoid downvoting, provide a [mcve] of what you have attempted so far and describing what step did not work. See [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
    import re
    a='https://abcd.sample.com/templates/cp/assets/img/1_fs?123456'
    result=re.search(r'^https:\/\/abcd.sample.com\/[a-z,\/]*1_fs\?123456$',a)
    print result
```